# Issue with Flutter commands after Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter

My project was working okay before I got Flutter upgrade prompt. After accepting to upgrade flutter, I started getting the following exception and now with every flutter command I get this exception. Also since that problem started Android Studio does not pick up any running emulator. So basically, I'm stuck, please help. It just displays "Loading..." instead of displaying the running Emulator.

**Version Information:**

Android Studio 3.4.2 • Flutter plugin io.flutter 38.2.1 • Dart plugin 183.6270

I've change the permission for git.EXE to allow for read, execute etc but this has not helped.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

CreateProcessW failed 5
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: Access is denied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flutter doctor error on windows 10: CreateProcessW failed 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993909/flutter-doctor-error-on-windows-10-createprocessw-failed-5)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue after running the flutter upgrade command

Remove exiting flutter SDK from the directory "https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install" and download again and run the following command

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 0):

After running the `flutter upgrade` command in the Windows CMD I faced the same issue.

I then tried to upgrade Flutter SDK using the Android Studio terminal and it upgraded successfully.